# Migrating website - keeping databases in sync during migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I'm about to migrate a website from one service provider to another.
A previous migration was performed by a hosting company, which caused quite big issues with user data/posts/registrations being posted into 2 different servers, depending on which DNS server they used.
Merging the databases afterwards was difficult because on both databases, autoincrement values had moved on and when it was time to merge the 2 databases, primary key/ auto increment values were overlapping, resulting in either that row not being imported/inserted, or that row overwriting previous one.

Is there a way to ... redirect users who arrive at the old server to the new server to avoid databases getting out of sync.

Are there any tricks / tips i can use to avoid this happening again?

Comment: Hey, if i migrate from one Server to another i let the new one connect to the old database for like 2 days, so that both work on the same database while the dns-change is in progress.

Comment: I thought of something similar myself. What i had in mind, was ... well, to simply redirect users from the old one to the new one, using the new servers IP ( but im not sure if i can do that).
If i set the mysql hostname to www.myserver.com, then .. wont mysql get split results solving that url ? Is it safe to use IP.?
I know my question is confusing, but im not really a server guy :)

Answer (score 1):

Set both servers up and test to make sure they both work.

On the new server (one you are switching to) proxy all requests back to the old server Apache example

```
ProxyPass / http://oldip:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://oldip:80/
```

Switch the DNS to point at the new server.

Wait for 24-48 hours, Making sure all traffic is now being routed though the new server, back to the old server.

remove proxy settings.
stop apache
do a backup of the databases
send them to the new server
restore the database backups
start apache.

You can write a script to do that.

To speed up the database backups you could use the binlog so you only need to transfer the more recent one

When your happy the new server is working. stop the old server running.

Should work with a small amount of downtime.

Alternately, Reduce your TTL on the DNS (NOTE: Not all DNS caching respects this if its small) wait for that change to process
Switch to the new server, with a higher TTL, Due to the old TTL being really small, most people will not be effected.

Alternativly, make the current site read only until the switch has occurred.